# Laravel 5 Hasmanythrough inverse querying

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 models : Vehicle, Dealer and Province

Eloquent Relationships are as follows:

> Vehicle belongsTo Dealer
>
> Dealer hasMany Vehicles
>
> Province hasMany Dealers
>
> Dealer belongs to Province
>
> Province hasManyThrough Vehicles

I wanted to get all vehicles in a specific province , but my code need to start calling from vehicle model, because I am calling many filters to Vehicles.

My code:

```
    $p = 'Alberta';
    $d = Vehicle::whereHas('province', function($q) use ($p) {
        $q->where('province_name', $p);
        return $q;
    })->get();
    dd($d);
```

Unfortunately getting error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dealers.province_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `vehicles` where exists (select * from `provinces` where `dealers`.`province_id` = `provinces`.`id` and `province_name` = Alberta))

But province_id column do exist in dealers table. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `HasManyThrough` relationship does not have an inverse. Your Province can have many Vehicles through Dealers, but your Vehicle does not belong to a Province. Your Vehicle belongs to a Dealer that belongs to a Province.

Because of this, your `whereHas` needs to specify the nested relationship:

```
$p = 'Alberta';
$d = Vehicle::whereHas('dealer.province', function($q) use ($p) {
    return $q->where('province_name', $p);
})->get();
dd($d);
```

Comment: One more question please. Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168103

Comment: FYI, this (beautiful) query produces a result set of Vehicles which is "DISTINCT".  For example, say that **3** Vehicles match the criteria; the result set will contain only **1 record**, not 3.  Though the generated SQL query does't actually specify `DISTINCT()`, the results are `distinct` based on the criteria. To elaborate, the result set will not _always_ be a single record, but the result set will be `distinct` on whatever the criteria is.  For example, say your criteria matches **10** records which have **3** different values, the result set will contain **3** records.  Hope this helps!